# Problem with Apache PHP CURL and CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE authentication against EWS Exchange Webservice

Tags: php, curl, exchangewebservices, negotiate

I would like to establish a connection to the Microsoft Exchange Web Service (EWS) using PHP and CURL.
The authentication method should be negotiate.
Using NTLM is not desirable for security reasons, so you have to switch to Kerberos.

I use as System:
Windows OS with Apache 2.4.55
PHP 7.4.33
CURL has the following features:
Features
AsynchDNS Yes
CharConv No
Debug No
GSS Negotiate No
IDN Yes
IPv6 Yes
krb4 No
Large file Yes
libz Yes
NTLM Yes
NTLMWB No
SPNEGO Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI Yes
TLS SRP No
HTTP2 Yes
GSSAPI No
KERBEROS5 Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS Yes
PSL No
HTTPS_PROXY Yes
MULTI_SSL No
BROTLI No

We use: Exchange Server 2016 with extended protection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/security-best-practices/exchange-extended-protection?view=exchserver-2019

On the exchange server I created the http.keytab using ktpass, then integrated it into PHP and CURL.

I tried to establish the connection with the following PHP code:

```
$url = 'https://192.168.1.2/EWS/Exchange.asmx';
$keytabPath = 'c:\kerberos\http.keytab';
$servicePrincipal = "EXCH2016ASA@EXCHANGE2016.myEXCHANGE2016.local";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Negotiate"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SERVICE_NAME, $servicePrincipal);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, file_get_contents($keytabPath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYTAB, $keytabPath); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "EXCH2016ASA:");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The result is always an http 400 error (HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name).
How exactly do I have to set the CURL OPT settings in conjunction with CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you should be setting the `Authorization: Negotiate` header yourself? I'd expect cURL to automatically add that in the necessary form, when you specify CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your info. That was actually incorrect of me with 2 header entries. If I remove my Authorization: Netotiate then I now get an http 401 error.
How can I further find out where the problem with authentication is?